# Can't get XP style buttons (FlatStyle=System) in Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-xp, controls

I've tried a lot of solutions to get XP-style buttons on VB.NET using both FlatStyle=System for each button as well as using

```
Shared Sub Main()
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.Run(New Form1())
End Sub
```

within the Form1 Class, but it's not working.  All I can do is assume that I can't get XP-style buttons because my Windows 10 settings are not appropriate -- since the MSDN page states that for FlatStyle=System, the appearance of controls take on the OS settings.   Thus, what must one do in Windows 10 using VS 2015 in order to get XP-style buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I got XP styles working in Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 by adding the following Imports and modifying the constructor (New subroutine) for Form1:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles

Public Sub New()
     InitializeComponent()
     ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
     Application.VisualStyleState = VisualStyleState.NoneEnabled
End Sub
```

If you want to learn why the above solution is the way it is, then you should try looking at the MSDN example below, which I had to modify to get it running. First, in VS make a new Project, add a Form1 to it, and then paste all of the code below into Form1's code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles
Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form
    Private WithEvents button1 As New Button()
    Private radioButton1 As New RadioButton()
    Private radioButton2 As New RadioButton()
    Private radioButton3 As New RadioButton()
    Private radioButton4 As New RadioButton()

    Public Sub New()
        With button1
            .AutoSize = True
            .Location = New Point(10, 10)
            .Text = "Update VisualStyleState"
        End With

        With radioButton1
            .Location = New Point(10, 50)
            .AutoSize = True
            .Text = "Apply styles to client area only"
        End With

        With radioButton2
            .Location = New Point(10, 70)
            .AutoSize = True
            .Text = "Apply styles to nonclient area only"
        End With

        With radioButton3
            .Location = New Point(10, 90)
            .AutoSize = True
            .Text = "Apply styles to client and nonclient areas"
        End With

        With radioButton4
            .Location = New Point(10, 110)
            .AutoSize = True
            .Text = "Disable styles in all areas"
        End With

        Me.Text = "VisualStyleState Test"
        Me.Controls.AddRange(New Control() {button1, radioButton1,
                radioButton2, radioButton3, radioButton4})
    End Sub

    <STAThread()>
    Shared Sub Main()
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.Run(New Form1())
    End Sub

    Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
            Handles button1.Click

        If radioButton1.Checked Then
            Application.VisualStyleState =
                    VisualStyleState.ClientAreaEnabled
        ElseIf radioButton2.Checked Then
            Application.VisualStyleState =
                    VisualStyleState.NonClientAreaEnabled
        ElseIf radioButton3.Checked Then
            Application.VisualStyleState =
                    VisualStyleState.ClientAndNonClientAreasEnabled
        ElseIf radioButton4.Checked Then
            Application.VisualStyleState =
                    VisualStyleState.NoneEnabled
        End If

        ' Repaint the form and all child controls.
        Me.Invalidate(True)
    End Sub
```

At run-time, just click the various RadioButtons followed by clicking the Button1, and you will see the client (border) and non-client (inner controls) change thereafter.